# Format the index in connection with to_html in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I was hoping that it was possible to format the index (column) directly in connection with output to HTML with the to_html() in the Pandas DataFrame?

Something like:

```
df = DataFrame([[1, 2]], index=['a'], columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df.to_html(formatters={
    'index': lambda elem: '<a href="example.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(elem, elem)}, escape=False))
```

This does not work. I do not get a link.

I suppose I would need to do something like

```
dfc = df.copy()
dfc.index = ['<a href="example.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(i, i) for i in df.index]
print(dfc.to_html(escape=False))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `__index__` instead of `index`:

```
print(df.to_html(formatters={
    '__index__': lambda elem: '<a href="example.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(elem, elem)}, escape=False))
```

Source: [The pull request that introduced that feature](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/2409).